# low battery back up on my dell laptop xps 15 lx501 running on ubuntu14.04

Tags: dell, battery, dell-studio-xps-16, low-power

i am getting battery backup of 1:40 on my laptop when the battery is full charged.
battery is new so i doubt that there is any problem with that.
it was running perfectly fine on windows 7 this problem arises when i shifted to ubuntu .i am new to this ecosystem to please help me .